# How do you add a new line in a swift label.text

Tags: swift

I am making an app and I want to add a new line, in a Teach.text

```
func RandomQuestions(){

        var RandomNumber = arc4random() % 1
        RandomNumber += 1

        switch(RandomNumber){
        case 1:
            QuestionLbl.hidden = false
           QuestionLbl.text = "2x + 4 = 14"
            Button1.setTitle("x = 5", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
           Button2.setTitle("x = 4", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
           Button3.setTitle("x = 9", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button4.setTitle("y = 5", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Teach.text = "2x + 4 = 14"
            CorrectAnswer = "1"
            break

        default:
            break

        } 

    }
```

So in other words, I need to add another line, so when I am testing my app, the 'Teach' should say

2x + 4 = 14
2x = 10

Answer (score 15):

If it's a UILabel, set **numberOfLines** field to 0

```
Teach.numberOfLines = 0
Teach.text = "Line1\nLine2"
```

And make sure it's tall enough to show both lines.

Comment: if it answers your question, please don't forget to accept it.

Comment: Is this for swift 2.X version? It was not working for Swift 3.0? Can you suggest me something what to add?

Answer (score 3):

Just add the following code

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0 // 0 = unlimited lines, you can also set the in your storyboard
```

Hope that helps